# Fast way to detect/remove univariate outliers in R

Tags: r, outliers

Is there a faster way to detect outliers in R than the examples below?

**Requirement:** Outliers should by NA in the result vector.

```
vals = c(6.4, 1.786, 5.934, 6.689, 6.098, 6.177, 6.768, 6.31, 6.164,
         1.543, 6.242, 6.107, 6.708, 6.184, 6.102, 6.495, 6.423, 6.489,
         5.264, 5.09, 5.915, 6.114, 5.395, 5.991, 6.732, 6.143, 6.657,
         5.563, 5.173, 5.439, 4.305, 6.867, 5.007, 6.37, 6.193, 5.504,
         6.333, 6.25, 0.206, 5.911, 5.496, 0.093, 6.554, 6.25, 6.526,
         6.202, 6.305, 5.977, 6.476, 5.903, 5.758, 5.117, 6.985, 6.485,
         0.763, 5.368, 5.146, 3.079, 5.823, 5.627, 6.077, 6.346, 5.301,
         5.555, 6.02, 6.914, 5.896, 5.458, 6.473, 7.348, 7.649, 6.464,
         6.545, 6.673, 6.618, 6.659)


detect_outliers = function(x, na.rm = TRUE, ...) {
  qnt = stats::quantile(x, probs=c(.25, .75), na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  H = 1.5 * stats::IQR(x, na.rm = na.rm)
  y = x
  y[x < (qnt[1] - H)] = NA
  y[x > (qnt[2] + H)] = NA
  y
}

detect_outliers2 = function(x, ...) {
  out = suppressMessages(univOutl::boxB(x, ...))
  x[out$outliers] = NA
  x
}

detect_outliers3 = function(x) {
  out = graphics::boxplot(x, plot=FALSE)$out
  x[fastmatch::`%fin%`(x, out)] = NA
  x
}

detect_outliers4 = function(x) {
  out = grDevices::boxplot.stats(x)$out
  x[fastmatch::`%fin%`(x, out)] = NA
  x
}

detect_outliers5 = function(x) {
  out = rstatix::identify_outliers(data.frame(x))
  x[fastmatch::`%fin%`(x, out$x)] = NA
  x
}

detect_outliers6 = function(x) {
  dev = abs(x-median(x)) # absolute deviation from median
  MAD = median(abs(dev)) # median absolute deviation
  sd = MAD/0.67449
  x[dev > 2*sd] = NA
  x
}


rbenchmark::benchmark("detect_outliers" = detect_outliers(vals),
          "detect_outliers2" = detect_outliers2(vals),
          "detect_outliers3" = detect_outliers3(vals),
          "detect_outliers4" = detect_outliers4(vals),
          "detect_outliers5" = detect_outliers5(vals),
          "detect_outliers6" = detect_outliers6(vals),
          replications = 1000,
          columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed",
                      "relative", "user.self", "sys.self"))
```

***Benchmark results***

```
              test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
1  detect_outliers         1000   0.198    3.600     0.198    0.001
2 detect_outliers2         1000   0.350    6.364     0.331    0.019
3 detect_outliers3         1000   0.105    1.909     0.105    0.000
4 detect_outliers4         1000   0.070    1.273     0.070    0.000
5 detect_outliers5         1000   5.245   95.364     5.224    0.004
6 detect_outliers6         1000   0.055    1.000     0.055    0.001
```

***Outliers removed***

```
df = data.frame(method = factor(c(rep("detect_outliers", length(vals)),
                           rep("detect_outliers2", length(vals)),
                           rep("detect_outliers3", length(vals)),
                           rep("detect_outliers4", length(vals)),
                           rep("detect_outliers5", length(vals)),
                           rep("detect_outliers6", length(vals))),
                           levels = rev(c("detect_outliers", 
                                          "detect_outliers2", 
                                          "detect_outliers3", 
                                          "detect_outliers4", 
                                          "detect_outliers5", 
                                          "detect_outliers6"))),
                orig = rep(vals, 6),
                outlier_removed = c(detect_outliers(vals),
                                    detect_outliers2(vals),
                                    detect_outliers3(vals),
                                    detect_outliers4(vals),
                                    detect_outliers5(vals),
                                    detect_outliers6(vals)))

df$is_outlier = factor(ifelse(is.na(df$outlier_removed), "yes", "no"), 
                       levels = c("yes", "no"))

ggplot2::ggplot(df, ggplot2::aes(x = method, 
                                 y = orig, 
                                 color = is_outlier)) +
  ggplot2::geom_point(alpha = 0.5, size = 5) +
  ggplot2::theme_bw() +
  ggplot2::labs(x = "", y = "vals") +
  ggplot2::coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Was wondering where those benchmarks were.

Comment: well you could use `boxplot.stats` instead of `boxplot(..., plot = FALSE)` and there are still things in there you dont need so you could strip it down more

Comment: One requirement: Outliers should be kept in the result vector, just the values should be replaced by NA.

Comment: @rawr just added an example with boxplot.stats

Answer (score 1):

You can use `identify_outliers()` [rstatix package].

Comment: It's pretty slow compared to the other methdos